# Фильтрация dataframe по регулярному выражению в R

Tags: r

Есть dataframe

| id | answer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | строка |
| 2 | 34234 |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | NA |

Мне надо выбрать dataframe без пустой строки 3.
Пытаюсь через `dataframe %>% filter(answer==".")`
но понимаю, что это бред и запрос не правильный. как правильно фильтровать? Ошибка в регулярном выражении или в формате данных, которые выдает `answer=="."` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

регулярное выражение можно указать с помощью функции `grepl()` из пакета *base*.

данные:

```
> d <- data.frame(id=c(1:4),answer=c('строка','34234','','NA'))
> d
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
3  3       
4  4     NA
```

фильтр:

```
> d[grepl('.', d$answer),]
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
4  4     NA
```

если вам нужно именно с функцией `filter()` из пакета *dplyr*, то можно так:

```
> filter(d, grepl('.', answer))
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
3  4     NA
```

или так:

```
> d %>% filter(grepl('.', answer))
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
3  4     NA
```

---

другой вариант — функция `str_detect()` из пакета *stringr*:

```
> d[str_detect(d$answer, '.'),]
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
4  4     NA
> filter(d, str_detect(answer, '.'))
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
3  4     NA
> d %>% filter(str_detect(answer, '.'))
  id answer
1  1 строка
2  2  34234
3  4     NA
```